# Showing multiple results in search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've a bug in a search engine showing results.
Here's the code:

```
$nmanufacturer = $tApplication[2];

$manufac = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tManufacturers WHERE nManufacturer='$nmanufacturer'");
$manufacts = mysql_fetch_array($manufac);

//nom du constructeur
$contruct = $manufacts[1];

?>

<select class="form-control">
<option><?php echo $contruct; ?></option>
</select>
```

The probleme is that the option element shows only one result however there's many results in the database
 Hope you can Help Me Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bon jour! You have to do a while cicle.

```
$nmanufacturer = $tApplication[2];

$manufac = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tManufacturers WHERE Manufacturer='$nmanufacturer'");

?>

<select class="form-control">
<?php
while($manufact = mysql_fetch_array($manufac)) {
    echo '<option>' . $manufact[1] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

The mysql_fetch_array function returns an associative array, but it also returns FALSE if there are no more rows to return! Using a PHP While Loop we can use this information to our advantage.

If we place the statement "$row = mysql_fetch_array()" as our while loop's conditional statement we will accomplish two things:

1. We will get a new row of MySQL information that we can print out
   each time the while loop checks its conditional statement.
2. When there are no more rows the function will return FALSE causing the
   while loop to stop!

via http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php

Comment: Thanks Alot this realy helpful I'll try it

Comment: Thank you for accepting it as best answer, if you like my answer, I would be more than happy to get an upvote from you.